# How to inline all CSS in a Next.js v13 project?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am using https://panda-css.com/ with Next.js v13 (app folder).

The pages load as expected, e.g. https://ray.run/blog/mastering-poms

But if you look at the rendered HTML, it links to CSS assets, e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/3604df4459464cea.css" data-precedence="next"/>
```

I would like to inline this CSS in the response.

How do I do it?